# Roll 6 Dice using For Loop and check if all values are equal - Java

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm trying to make a program which rolls 6 dice using a for loop.

The problem with my program is that it only seems to check the value of two instances of the Die. I'm trying to get it so the for loop compares all 6 dice' values and displays the amount of tries it took for all 6 dice to reach the same value.

Currently, when I run the program, the tries it takes is around 2-13. The expected result, however is a huge number such as 3000 because of how many instances there are and the randomness given. Hopefully what I said makes sense.

Basically, I have a Die class that looks like this:

```
public class Die {

    private int faces;
    private int value;

    public Die() {
        this.faces = 6;
        rollDie();
    }

    public void rollDie() {
        this.value = (int) (Math.random() * this.faces + 1);
    }

    public boolean isSameValue(Die die) {
        return die.getValue() == this.value;
    }
}
```

And here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Die[] die = new Die[6];
    int[] dieValue = new int[die.length];
    int counter = 0;
    boolean exitProgram = false;

    do {

        counter++;

        int currentValue, lastValue = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < die.length; i++) {

            die[i] = new Die();

            dieValue[i] = die[i].getValue();

            currentValue = i;

            if (i > 0 && dieValue[lastValue] == dieValue[i]) {
                exitProgram = true;
            }
            else {
                exitProgram = false;
            }

            lastValue = currentValue;

        }
    }
    while(!exitProgram);

    System.out.println(counter);

}
```

What fix can I do to the code so that it compares the value of all six dice and returns the amount of tries it took?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an if statement that keeps creating a new die in the loop. That if statement will check if the value is 6, otherwise it count and give the die a new value.  Once the temp value is 6 it will exit.

```
    int counter = 0;
    boolean exitProgram = false;
    int tempValue = 0;

    do{
        Die die = new Die();
        tempValue = die.getValue();

        if (tempValue != 6) {
        /*System.out.println(tempValue);*/
            counter++;
        }
        else {
            /*System.out.println(tempValue);*/
            exitProgram= true;
        }
    }while  (!exitProgram) ;
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In the conditional statement checking whether to exit program, you don't need to do anything in case the current value is the same as the last value. Instead, you assume they are always the same, and not exit program when you see the first difference:

```
if (dieValue[lastValue] != dieValue[i]) {
    exitProgram = false;
    break;
}
```

And at the beginning of the while loop, you also need to reset the `exitProgram` variable to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like your code is doing right now is making all the dice be the same as the first die, instead of constantly rolling all 6 dice.
For example, if die 1 is 4, it will keep going until all dice are equal to 4.

If you want it to be randomly rolling all 6 dice at a time, you need to do something like this:

```
do {

        //Creating a new array of 6 dice
        Die[] die = new Die[6];

        counter++;

        for(int i = 0; i < die.length; i++) {
            die[i] = new Die();
        }
        //Get the first value of the array, since they all have to be the same
        int value = die[0];
        //Set the boolean to true, it gets overwritten in the following for loop if false
        exitProgram = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < die.length; j++) {
            if (die[j] != value)
                exitProgram = false;
                break;
            }
        } 

    }
    while(!exitProgram);
```

I did not run that in a compiler, so let me know if there are any errors.